# Configuring Nginx to serve two different static website builds

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I'm trying to configure Nginx in an Ubuntu 20.04 machine to load 2 different static builds. One for the `development`  and another one for  `staging`.

However I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error" when I visit the domains. I think the problem could be that `listen` part on the `server {}` but can't be sure. Maybe it is something else?

I'm new to Nginx and server configuration.

My `config` files for the sites

```
 server {
    listen 80;  # [ASK]: is this what's causing the problem ? 
    root /home/user/user-frontend/website/build/; ## development build
    index index.html;

    server_name frontend.develop.mysite.be;  ## development domain


    charset  utf-8;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
      text/plain
      text/css
      text/js
      text/xml
      text/javascript
      application/javascript
      application/x-javascript
      application/json
      application/xml
      application/xml+rss;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location @rewrites {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

      location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }

      location ~* \.(?:css|js)\$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
      
      location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
      }
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, authorization';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';
  }

   server {
    listen 80;  # [ASK]: is this what's causing the problem ? 
    root /home/user/user-frontend-staging/website/build/; ## staging build
    index index.html;

    server_name frontend.staging.mysite.be;  ## staging domain

    charset utf-8;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
      text/plain
      text/css
      text/js
      text/xml
      text/javascript
      application/javascript
      application/x-javascript
      application/json
      application/xml
      application/xml+rss;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location @rewrites {
      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
    }

      location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)\$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }

      location ~* \.(?:css|js)\$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }
      
      location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
      }

      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept, authorization';
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';
  }
```

Comment: No, `listen` directive isn't the cause of error. I don't see anything that can be the cause. What is the corresponding error log message? `location @rewrites { ... }` isn't referred anywhere and should be removed. Replace `\$` with `$` on two regex matching locations. Change `/.well-known` to `/\.well-known`. Remove the trailing slash from the `root` path parameter.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I didn't get any log messages except the `500 Server Error`.  But I did your fixes and it is  working now. I think that trailing slash from `root` was causing the problem. Thanks  once again. If you want repost your comment as an answer so I can mark it as an answer and what not.